# Copy data to another sheet based on supplier number and given dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet that currently looks something like this:

[image]

I'd like to enter a supplier number and a date range in a sheet (example below) and that the data that fulfills the criteria is copied to a new sheet

[image]

So let's say, I enter supplier number "00X12345" and From 23/08/2022 to 27/08/2022, so it'd copy this data:

[image]

Does anyone know if this would be possible using VBA?

Comment: `Does anyone know if this would be possible using VBA?` Yes it is possible using vba.

Comment: We can provide more specific help if you provide code that you've tried and need specific help to get working.

Comment: This can be done both formulaically without VBA, and also with VBA.